# Different icons alignment at Gmail and Browser

Tags: html, css

I created HTML for one of the emailers, it looks perfect on Browser but in Gmail, it looks opposite to the browser. I followed many StackOverflow links but it didn't help.
Following are the screenshots of the browser, Gmail & code.

**Browser:**
[Browser Icons alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDJJB.png)

**Gmail:**
[Gmail Icons alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPlbk.png)

**Code Snippet:**

```
<td width="100%">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href=""><img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/instagram-new.png" /></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/facebook-new.png" /></a>
                            <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/linkedin.png" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
```

Comment: How are you setting the width of the parent table? Perhaps it would help us track this down if you gave us more complete code?

Answer (score 0):

This standalone code works for me in GMail as well. Looks like the width of the container is not sufficient in your setup. In this case the icons will rearrange under each other.
You might want to add an absolute width like

```
        <td width="100%">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><div style="width: 160px;">
                        <a href=""><img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/48/000000/instagram-new.png" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/facebook-new.png" /></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/linkedin.png" /></a></div>                        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work      https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDJJB.png

Comment: Mmh, but in the screenshot above the icons are next to each other. Wasn't that the plan? What is not working? Maybe we need a more complete code indeed....